# Router's web based control panel gone

Tags: router

We have a Netgear FVS336G router in our network that was accessible through 192.168.2.1 in the web browser before.

When I was connecting to IRC services such as freenode, they used to ban me because supposedly I had a proxy server installed. I believed it was the web interface of the router that made IRC servers think it's a proxy server, so I tried to make the web interface inaccessible from the Internet by turning "remote management" off.

This fixed the problem of connecting to IRC servers, but now the router is no longer accessible through the web interface so I can't make changes to the firewall settings.

How do I gain access back?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [Factory Reset](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/74/~/fvs336g---general-product-information-&-features#q7).

The above link was the first hit when I googled **factory reset Netgear FVS336G**, sometimes you just need to know the correct term.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates you are not connected to the router in the same subnet. If your IP is different to 192.168.2.xxx  you are possibly behind a second router, e.g. a wlan router or something like that.

For further troubleshooting a more detailed description of your network could be helpful.

Comment: When I do ipconfig /all, I get the folllowings IPv4 Address : 192.168.2.161, Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0, Default Gateway : 192.168.2.1, doesn't this show we are in the same subnet?

Comment: absolutely. then it's even more strange your router is not allowing access. you may follow the factory reset suggestion